# One or more errors occurred (Clea-text HTTP traffic to 192.168.0.18 not permitted Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, upload

I need help. I am trying to upload a file using "MultipartFormDataContent" and "HttpClient", but I get an error. I see there are a lot of people in the same situation but their solutions do not work for me.

> event click to upload

```java
private async void upload_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),
        "\"file\"",
        $ "\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var uploadServiceBaseAdress = "http://192.168.0.18/upload";

    Console.WriteLine(_mediaFile.Path);
    try {
        var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAdress, content);
        message.Text = httpResponseMessage.Result.Content.ToString();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        await DisplayAlert("non", error.Message, "ok");
    }
}
```

> manifest

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"></application>
```

> Resources > xml > network_security_config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.18</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

On line `var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAdress, content);`
I get the following error:

```
One or more errors occurred (Clea-text HTTP traffic to 192.168.0.18 not permitted Xamarin forms
```

Do you have any solution?

**EDIT**
It work's fine with production server with HTTPS but I need that it work's in development server (192.168.0.18). How can i resolve this issue

Comment: Do you mind adding the error you get to your post?

Comment: It's in the title of the post :) "One or more errors occurred (Clea-text HTTP traffic to 192.168.0.18 not permitted", thank's for your reply

Comment: My bad! I see now. Thanks :)

Comment: haha no problem

Comment: `My bad! I see now.` No. Not your bad but @willisMonteiro's bad. Rule 1, lesson 1: Never refer to the subject. All info should be in the post.

Comment: you are supplying an IP address instead of a domain name.  Try setting `android:usesCleartextTraffic` in your manifest instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to document [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

The easy way to implement this is to use this attribute to your `AndroidManifest.xml` where you allow all http for all requests: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
```

**Another** method: replacing `domain-config` with `base-config`

XML `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
 </network-security-config>
```

and use in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will try at the end of the day